# Incorrect Array Sorting in Angular 6

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor, httpservice

I m using *ngFor to iterate array of objects in data-table and for serial no. i using `let index of i` and then printing it to the table but the problem i m facing is that after 9th serial no. i got 10 but after 1 serial no. like 1, 10, 11, 2, 3. Can anyone help me with this? 
Here's my typescript code and html code.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

```
// GETTING BONUS DATA
 getAllJobposts() {
 this.apiService.hrService.getAllJobPost().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.jobPostsData = res.data;
  console.log(this.jobPostsData);
  // this.DataTablesFunctionCallAfterDataInit()
 });
}

 <tr class="MousePointer" (click)="EditRecord(post.id, target)" *ngFor="let 
   post of jobPostsData | reverse; let i = index">

              <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
              <td>
                <span style="display: inline">
                  <a class=" btn btn-link btn-sm " title="Delete" [id]="post.id" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();modal.ShowModal(post.id)">
                    <i [ngStyle]="{color: 'blue'}" class="fa fa-trash-o ">
                    </i>
                  </a>
                  <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-round" title="Edit" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();EditRecord(post.id,target)">
                    <i [ngStyle]="{color: 'blue'}" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o "></i>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </td>
              <td>{{ post.jobTitle }}</td>
              <td>{{ getDepartmentName(post.departmentId) }}</td>
              <td>{{ getDesignationName(post.designationId) }}</td>
              <td>{{ post.totalPosition }}</td>
              <td>{{ post.minExperience }}</td>
              <td>{{ getCityName(post.cityId) }}</td>
              <td>
                <span [class]="post.active == 1? 'status success':'status danger'" style="width:60px !important; text-align: center;">
                  {{post.active == 1? "Active":"In-Active" }}
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Please post stackblitz

Comment: Show your `reverse` pipe.

Comment: Well i tried without reverse pipe. but same result

Comment: @AbdulBasit the project is really big so that's why i can't post it to stackblitz...

Comment: is `res.data` sorted correctly?

Comment: @MohammadQuanit i think your array is not sorted properly.. Try to remove the `pipe` from your loop

Comment: @Arikael yes, it is sorted but it's just not working properly in html table

Comment: Looks like it's sorting your column as a string and not a number. It's hard to say exactly what the problem is without seeing the rest of your code. What table element are you using?

Comment: @DarrenLamb i m using datatable from https://datatables.net/

Comment: Can you please update the example to show the table and how you initialise it? Both the HTML and the TS

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need rewrite your `reverse` pipe by something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'reverse' })
export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    return value.sort((a, b) => {
      return (b.id - a.id);
    }); 
  }
}
```

In sort function you need to specify object filed for sorting: 
`return (b.id - a.id)`.

Or use `parseInt(b.id) - parseInt(a.id)` if id's are strings (otherwise it will output the same result as in your screenshot, i.e. alphabetically)

Additionally you can pass object field for sorting via [parameters of pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe)